# How do i get this IF with arrays to work?

Tags: arrays, excel

[image: data]

Hi so see the data in the image. The Week Ending Date data is in column I and Employee name is in J.
I'm trying to do this formula but it only comes TRUE when the second condition (employee name) is True for the first one {1,0,0,0} versus {0,1,0,0}

```
=IF(($I$6:$I$11=10/30/2020)*($K$6:$K$11="Byrne, Lauren T."), TRUE, FALSE)
```

So in effect it only comes true for lauren but false for everyone else. Help please!

Comment: Sorry i mean the employee name is in K

Comment: `($I$6:$I$11="10/30/2020")`